# Jenkins: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

Tags: 20.04, jenkins

While studying Jenkins tool, I am trying to execute a simple command on my private Ubunto machine, and I get the error message in subject.

[image]

So far, all my attempts failed:

```
sudo -S ps -ef | grep jenkins < password.secret
sudo -S ps -ef | grep jenkins < <my secret admin password>
echo <my secret admin password> | sudo -S ps -ef | grep jenkins
sudo -S <<< <my secret admin password> ps -ef | grep jenkins
```

How can I fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: Your commands look fine. I suppose that Jenkins will use user that don't have `sudo` permissions. Check your `/var/log/auth.log` for `user NOT in sudoers` messages.